# Why does my REST API return blank JSON on nested objects?

Tags: java, json, rest, heroku

I'm trying to retrieve all the posts from Heroku app database given an email id

I have a **Query** class that processes all the requests (for now just `GET`)

Following is **Query.java**

```
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

import com.auro.assignment.wallpostapi.model.PostBundle;

@Path("query")
public class Query {

    public Query() {

    }

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public PostBundle getPostBundle() {

        PostManager postManager = new PostManager();
        return postManager.getPostBundle("xyz.123@test.in");

    }

}
```

Then I have something called **PostManager** that bundles all the posts with a status code and a message.

Following is the **PostManager.java**

```
    import java.io.PrintWriter;
    import java.io.StringWriter;
    import java.net.URISyntaxException;
    import java.sql.Connection;
    import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
    import java.sql.ResultSet;
    import java.sql.SQLException;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    import com.auro.assignment.wallpostapi.dbconnection.DBConnectionManager;
    import com.auro.assignment.wallpostapi.model.*;

    public class PostManager {

        private PostBundle postBundle;
        private List<Post> posts;

        public PostManager() {
            postBundle = null;
            posts = new ArrayList<>();
        }

        public PostBundle getPostBundle(final String email) {

            try {
                Connection connection = DBConnectionManager.getConnection();
                final String query = "SELECT user_post, post_time FROM wall_post WHERE user_id = " +
                                                        "(SELECT user_id FROM user_info WHERE user_email = ?);";

                PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(query);
                preparedStatement.setString(1, email);
                ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

                if  (resultSet != null && resultSet.next()) {
                    while (resultSet.next()) {
                        posts.add(new Post(resultSet.getString("user_post"),resultSet.getString("post_time")));
                    }
                    postBundle = new PostBundle("200","SUCCESS!",posts);
                    return postBundle;
                }
                else {
                    postBundle = new PostBundle("404","NOT FOUND",null);
                    return postBundle;
                }           
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException | URISyntaxException | SQLException e) {
                StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
                PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(stringWriter);
                e.printStackTrace(printWriter);
                String stackTrace = stringWriter.toString();
                postBundle = new PostBundle("500",stackTrace,null);
                return postBundle;
            }

        }
    }

Following is the **PostBundle.java**

import java.util.List;

public class PostBundle {

    private String status;
    private String message;
    private List<Post> posts;

    public PostBundle() {
        status = null;
        message = null;
        posts = null;
    }

    public PostBundle(final String status, final String message, final List<Post> posts) {
        this.status = status;
        this.message = message;
        this.posts = posts;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public List<Post> getPosts() {
        return posts;
    }

}
```

And finally, following is the **Post.java**

```
public class Post {

    private String data;
    private String date;

    public Post() {
        data = null;
        date = null;
    }

    public Post(final String data, final String date) {
        this.data = data;
        this.date = date;
    }

    public String getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

}
```

It is returning a blank JSON at [this site](http://wallpostapi.herokuapp.com/webapi/query)

Is there anything wrong with how I designed the architecture? I'm guessing there is some kind of internal error taking place, but in PostManager method, I make sure any error stacktrace also gets bundled, yet I'm getting an absolute blank screen.

Comment: Did the proposed solution work for you? If yes, can you accept the solution? If not, can you tell us what is still not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see some errors here:

**First, you call `resultSet.next()` twice**

```
// Initially the cursor is positioned before the first row.
ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

if  (resultSet != null && resultSet.next()) { // The cursor is moved to the first row
    while (resultSet.next()) { // The cursor is moved to the second row, so you skipped the
                               // first result and it only iterates from second to last one
        ...
    }
    postBundle = new PostBundle("200","SUCCESS!",posts); // posts only contains from
                                                         //second to last result. In case
                                                         //you only have one result,
                                                         //posts is an empty ArrayList

    return postBundle;
}
```

How many posts does the "xyz.123@test.in" email have? If it has only one, that's the issue.

**Second, `preparedStatement.executeQuery()` never returns `null`**

So you don't need to check if it is `null`.

**Third, if an email has not any posts should never return a 404, but a 200 instead with an empty json.**

> 200 OK - The request has succeeded. The information returned with the
>   response is dependent on the method used in the request.
>
> 404 Not Found - The server has not found anything matching the
>   Request-URI.

The 404 error is reserved for request-URI matching.

**Finally, you should modify your code accordingly:**

You should modify your code for the following:

```
...
try {
    Connection connection = DBConnectionManager.getConnection();
    final String query = "SELECT user_post, post_time FROM wall_post WHERE user_id = " +
            "(SELECT user_id FROM user_info WHERE user_email = ?);";

    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(query);
    preparedStatement.setString(1, email);
    ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

    while (resultSet.next()) {
        posts.add(new Post(resultSet.getString("user_post"),resultSet.getString("post_time")));
    }
    postBundle = new PostBundle("200","SUCCESS!",posts);
    return postBundle;         
}
...
```